# Install pfSense from USB Stick

Tags: pfsense

Is it possible to install pfSense from a USB stick, or will I need an external CD drive?

Comment: questions that are very pfSense-specific may be better asked on the pfsense forums or mailing list...

Comment: @ErikA: Ok, will do!

Comment: I generally agree, you're going to get the best attention there. Though I do hang out here a bit (I'm one of the project's founders), and you won't get any better advice. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run from it if you're using the embedded version, but if you're looking to do a full install, it's not possible with the stable version, you need a CD drive. There are USB stick equivalents of the iso for 2.0 at snapshots.pfsense.org.

Comment: +1 Can't get much more of a definitive answer than from one of the primary developers.

Answer (score 2):

pfSense can be written directly to the USB stick, and you can boot and run it from that.  pfSense doesn't have anything in the official docs about installing from a USB stick, which means it's likely going to be difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just get yourself an 8GB USB, Download the latest version of pfsense from their website, while downloading choose the console type as VGA. Once the image is downloaded, create a bootable Pfsense USB, and lastly boot from it, you can read more about [installing pfsense from USB](https://tekgru.com/how-to-install-pfsense-2-5-1-from-usb-easy-guide-2021/) in this article and it also explains the initial setup for pfsense.